# Trying to get property of non-object while passing array of data to controller in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5

When i am passing an associative array of data to controller its showing error that
'trying to get non-object property'
my controller function is,

```
        public function storeWBS(Request $request) {
        foreach($request->all() as $value){
            $formValue                = new WorkBreakdownStructure;
            $formValue->form_field_id = $value->idea_id;
            $formValue->value         = $value->wbs_description;
            $formValue->save();

        return back();}

    }
```

i have set the variables 'fillable' in model

> 'id'     ,'form_field_id'    ,'value'
>   if i print the '$formValue' with DD() i am getting the result

```
#parameters: array:4 [▼
  "_token" => "u6iwKspevWLiuI6CRPhd82c8xm0EYb6IGQQJX2aR"
  "idea_id" => array:3 [▼
    0 => "1"
    1 => "1"
    2 => "1"
  ]
  "wbs_description" => array:3 [▼
    0 => "Work Breakdown Structure #1 :"
    1 => "Work Breakdown Structure #2"
    2 => "Work Breakdown Structure #3"
  ]
  "percentage" => array:3 [▼
    0 => "50"
    1 => "12"
    2 => "12"
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 1):

`all()` returns array, not object so you cannot access it as you do now:

```
.... = $value->idea_id;
```

Instead you need to change this and use array syntax:

```
.... = $value['idea_id'];
```

**EDIT**

You also should remove `forach()` because you basically iterate over the array which makes no sense:

```
public function storeWBS(Request $request) {
      $value = $request->all();
            $formValue                = new WorkBreakdownStructure;
            $formValue->form_field_id = $value->idea_id;
            $formValue->value         = $value->wbs_description;
            $formValue->save();

        return back();
}
```

Also you need to fix `return back();` line. whatever `back()` refers to, you most likely invoking it wrong.

Comment: Dear @Marcin Orlowski i also try this but its returning error
`Illegal string offset 'idea_id'`

Comment: What you see when you do `var_dump($value);` or `DD($value);` in your loop?

Comment: i am getting only the token value not an array
don't know whats wrong
`"u6iwKspevWLiuI6CRPhd82c8xm0EYb6IGQQJX2aR`
@Marcin

Comment: if i remove for loop then i am getting grammar error

`Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize() must be of the type array, string given,`